# How to render and export audios in AudioKit?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, export, audiokit

I'm building a project about music and I am using the AudioKit framework. 
AudioKit is being very useful, but I need now to export sounds created in the app.

I'm using AKSequencer to play notes in sequence and I'm also applying some filters on the sound, like reverb.

I found a example code [here](https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Playback/Exporting%20Files/) that exports an audio from another audio file, but it is not what I need. Actually, I need to render the notes sequence, including the filters, and export it to the user.

My code:

```
class Sequencer {

    let oscBank = AKOscillatorBank(waveform: AKTable(AKTableType.positiveReverseSawtooth))//1
    let sequencer = AKSequencer()

    init() {
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        // I instantiate a MIDI node with the oscillator bank to put it in the track output.
        // It makes the oscillator's filters are recognized in the track output.
        let midiNode = AKMIDINode(node: oscBank)
        _ = sequencer.newTrack()
        sequencer.tracks[0].setMIDIOutput(midiNode.midiIn)

        generateSequence()

        // Here I'm applying some filter, a reverb in this case.
        let reverb = AKReverb(oscBank)
        reverb.loadFactoryPreset(.plate)

        // The Audiokit's output may be the last filter applyed. It is working to play.
        AudioKit.output = AKMixer(reverb)
        try? AudioKit.start()
    }

    func play() {
        sequencer.play()
    }

    func stop() {
        sequencer.stop()
    }


    /// Generates some melody (Sweet Child of Mine)
    func generateSequence() {
        for _ in 0..<2 {
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 62, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 0), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 74, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 0.5), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 1), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 67, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 1.5), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 79, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 2), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 2.5), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 78, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 3), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 3.5), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 62, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 4), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 74, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 4.5), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 5), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 67, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 5.5), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 79, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 6), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 6.5), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 78, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 7), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 7.5), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.5))
        }
    }


    // Here is my problem. I want to get the song and export it with the .wav extension exactly as it was played.
    // This code is just one of my many attempts and it also does not works.
    func saveFile() {
        guard let auxiliarPlayer = try? AKAudioPlayer(file: AKAudioFile(readFileName: "bass.wav")) else { return }
        guard let outputURL = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("audio_file.m4a") else { return }
        guard let output = try? AKAudioFile(forWriting: outputURL, settings: auxiliarPlayer.audioFile.fileFormat.settings) else { return }

        try? AudioKit.renderToFile(output, seconds: sequencer.tracks[0].length, prerender: {
            self.sequencer.play()
        })
    }
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, offline rendering does not work with MIDI due to timing issues. Basically, only things that process audio can be rendered, not things that rely on MIDI.  I believe it has to do with the MIDI clock remaining constant and not being able to be virtually "sped up" to match the audio rendering speed.

Comment: Aurelius, what do you suggest we do? This feature is essential in our project.

Comment: Do not you have any suggestions?

Comment: Someone will have to create a sequencer that is based on audio samples rather than midi timestamps for this to work.

Comment: Does this problem remain unsolved? We need offline rendering of MIDI sequences in our project as well.